# CSS - style horizontal line

Tags: css

I need to style a horizontal line `<hr>` like the picture attached. Is there any way to do this with pure css that would also work in IE8?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Sorry, I missed your IE8 requirement...this probably won't work there.  I apologize.  I don't have access to it to check.

You can use the :before and create a box, rotate it, apply some border, absolutely position it and voila, there you have it:

http://jsfiddle.net/v7y1bp9s/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <hr class="line"></hr>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1978a4;
    line-height: 50px;
}
hr.line {
    border-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
hr.line:before {
     content: '';
     height: 10px;
     width: 10px;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     transform: rotate(45deg);
     position: absolute;
     left: 50px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
     border-right: 1px solid #fff;
     background-color: #1978a4;
     top: -5px;
```

}

Comment: The background should be transparent. I just attached a screenshot of the mockup. So when I removed the bg color it is like this: http://jsfiddle.net/v7y1bp9s/2/

Any chance of getting the shape properly?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to make that shape that allows you to add the borders like you need.  Also, it can't be a transparent background, the color of the shape is needed to cover that small part of the <hr> to make it appear how it did in my fiddle.  Making it transparent simply exposes the <hr> and defeats the purpose.